# The convergence of sum $\sum{\frac {(N^3 + 2n^5 -n^6)}{(n^2+n^4+2n^8)}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The convergence of series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac {(n^3 + 2n^5 -n^6)}{(n^2+n^4+2n^8)}}$$Preferably with the comparison test.

Comment: $N$ or $n$ ? Summation bounds are ...?

Comment: I think it would be slightly easier to use the limit comparison test with the convergent p-series $\sum 1/n^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n>0$ $n^2+n^4+2n^8 \geq 2n^8$, so:

$$\frac{|n^3+2n^5-n^6|}{|n^2+n^4+2n^8|} \leq \frac{|n^3+2n^5-n^6|}{2n^8} $$

Next by triangle inequality:

$$\frac{|n^3+2n^5-n^6|}{2n^8} \leq \frac{n^3}{2n^8}+\frac{2n^5}{2n^8}+\frac{n^6}{2n^8}$$

But the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{2n^8}+\frac{2n^5}{2n^8}+\frac{n^6}{2n^8}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^5}+\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{2n^2}$$

converges.

Comment: Your very first equality is pretty odd though boring.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{n^{3}+2n^{5}-n^{6}}{n^{2}+n^{4}+2n^{8}}\right|=\left|\frac{n^{-3}+2n^{-3}-1}{n^{-4}+n^{-2}+2n^{2}}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n^{-4}+n^{-2}+2n^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$